# iOS Stretching View using Auto Layout in Landscape

Tags: ios, rotation, autolayout

I just started using Auto Layout for my upcoming projects. I created an UIImageView inside a UIScrollView like shown in the image below:

[image: UIScrollView with UIImageView]

Auto Layout works as expected and positions the UImageView correctly after rotation. My problem is that I want the UIImageView to stretch in Landscape Mode so that it fills the whole width. How can I do that? At the moment it has the same size as in Portrait Mode.

When I place the UIImageView directly in the UIViewControllers View without using an UIScrollView it stretches correctly. Why is that? I would be happy for some hints.

I am using the following constraints (Leading and Trailing Space are equal 0):
[image: Constraints]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out that using Auto Layout, UIImageView always inherits the size of its UIImage. So if I change the image on rotation the UIImageView just resizes properly.